# How to make a for loop with exception handling when key not in dictionary?

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary, exception

So, I have a dictionary with country names and corresponding stock index. The user is asked to enter five different countries and the program takes the five corresponding stock indexes and does something with the data.

When asked for input I check against the dictionary if the country can be found, this happens five times. Now, the part where the exception is handled is not doing what I hoped. What is wrong with my loop and/or exception handling??

```
ex_dict = {'United States': '^GSPC','United States of America': '^GSPC', 'Usa': '^GSPC', 'Argentina': '^MERV'} #shortened on purpose

countries = []
print('Please choose five stock exchanges to analyse,' )
print('just name the corresponding countries \n')

for i in range(0, 5):
    while True:
        try:
            countr = input('Please enter country no. %d: ' %(i+1))
            countr = countr.title()            
            if countr in ex_dict.keys():
                print('Found the corresponding stock index! \n')
                countries.append(countr)
            break
        except KeyError:
            print('Country not found, please try again! \n')
```

Comment: What are you hoping it to do, and what does it do instead?

Comment: You don't need to catch the KeyError, since you won't encounter one. Also use `if countr in ex_dict` instead of `if countr in ex_dict.keys()`

Comment: a simple else statement instead of the catching of KeyError would solve your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be no `KeyError` here because your code never tires to access the dictionary, just checks if the key is in `keys`. You could simply do this to achieve the same logic:

```
ex_dict = {'United States': '^GSPC','United States of America': '^GSPC', 'Usa': '^GSPC', 'Argentina': '^MERV'} #shortened on purpose

countries = []
print('Please choose five stock exchanges to analyse,' )
print('just name the corresponding countries \n')

for i in range(0, 5):
    while True:
        countr = input('Please enter country no. %d: ' %(i+1))
        countr = countr.title()
        if countr in ex_dict.keys():
            print('Found the corresponding stock index! \n')
            countries.append(countr)
            break
        else:
            print('Country not found, please try again! \n')
```

Sample run:

```
Please choose five stock exchanges to analyse,
just name the corresponding countries 

Please enter country no. 1: sdf
Country not found, please try again! 

Please enter country no. 1: USA
Found the corresponding stock index! 

Please enter country no. 2: Aregtng
Country not found, please try again! 

Please enter country no. 2: Argentina
Found the corresponding stock index! 

Please enter country no. 3: United States
Found the corresponding stock index! 

Please enter country no. 4: usa
Found the corresponding stock index! 

Please enter country no. 5: usa
Found the corresponding stock index!
```

Note: `.keys()` is overkill: to check if a key is in a dictionary you only need `k in some_dict`

Answer (score 0):

Your break is not in the if scope... so it will break on the first attempt.

Comment: Did you try the code? It loops through fine both with and without errors.

Comment: I meant that a while loop with a break that is guaranteed to fire makes no sense. But I admit that didn't answer your question about catching the exception... As said by the others, the code didn't raise any KeyError when trying `countr in ex_dict.keys()`

Answer (score 0):

From the [doc](https://wiki.python.org/moin/KeyError)

> Python raises a KeyError whenever a dict() object is requested (using the format a = adict[key]) and the key is not in the dictionary.

In your piece of code if you want print a message when user inserts a key not present in the countries dict, you can simply add an else statement instead of catch exception.

You can change your code in this way:

```
if countr in ex_dict.keys():
     print('Found the corresponding stock index! \n')
     countries.append(countr)
     break
else:
    print('Country not found, please try again! \n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of points:

- You code never going to hit exception since you are checking key existence using `if key in dict.keys()`
- Also, there are so many loops. I think `for i in range(0,5)` is enough.Will be **less complicated**.

  ```
  ex_dict = {'United States': '^GSPC','United States of America': '^GSPC', 'Usa': '^GSPC', 'Argentina': '^MERV'} #shortened on purpose

  countries = []
  print('Please choose five stock exchanges to analyse,' )
  print('just name the corresponding countries \n')

  for i in range(0, 5):
      countr = raw_input('Please enter country no. %d: ' %(i+1))
      countr = countr.title()
      if countr in ex_dict.keys():
          print('Found the corresponding stock index! \n')
          countries.append(countr)
      else:
          print('Country not found, please try again! \n')
  ```

**Output:**

```
C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>python c.py
Please choose five stock exchanges to analyse,
just name the corresponding countries

Please enter country no. 1: USA
Found the corresponding stock index!

Please enter country no. 2: asd
Country not found, please try again!

Please enter country no. 3: asd
Country not found, please try again!

Please enter country no. 4: USA
Found the corresponding stock index!

Please enter country no. 5: United states
Found the corresponding stock index!


C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want it to give you a message if the stock is not in the dictionary ex_dict, I have modified the code to do the same.

```
ex_dict = {'United States': '^GSPC','United States of America': '^GSPC', 'Usa': '^GSPC', 'Argentina': '^MERV'} #shortened on purpose

countries = []
print('Please choose five stock exchanges to analyse,' )
print('just name the corresponding countries \n')

for i in range(0, 5):
    while True:
        try:
            countr = input('Please enter country no. %d: ' %(i+1))
            countr = countr.title()            
            if countr not in ex_dict.keys():
                print ('Try again!')
            else:
                print('Found the corresponding stock index! \n')
                countries.append(countr)
```